# Java Config @Bean not autowired in other @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, config, autowired

Trying to setup a Spring 4 web application with Java Config, I encounter a problem with autowiring a bean created in a configuration class into another configuration class.
The 'dataSource' bean has a null value in the MyBatisConfig class. This seems to be the only bean in the configuration that doesn't get wired properly. Looking at the Spring debug logs (see last part of logs in the last code block below) it looks instantiated properly, but also seems to be destroyed?. What could be wrong in my configuration?

PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerConfig class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
public class PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

        propertyConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        /*propertyConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties"));
        propertyConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/var/lib/openshift/517874b8e0b8cd218e000391/app-root/data/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/conf/application.properties"));*/

        propertyConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
        propertyConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        return propertyConfigurer;
    }

}
```

DbConfig class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.config;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import({PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerConfig.class})
public class DbConfig {

    private @Value("jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DATABASE}") String url;
    private @Value("${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}") String username;
    private @Value("${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}") String password;

    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DbConfig.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Creating dataSource bean, url =  "+ url);

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);

        log.debug("dataSource bean url = "+ dataSource.getUrl());
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

MyBatisConfig class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.config;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

@Configuration
@Import({DbConfig.class})
public class MyBatisConfig {

    @Autowired private BasicDataSource dataSource;


    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyBatisConfig.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() {
        log.debug("Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = " + dataSource);

        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory =  new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] classPathResources;
        try {
            classPathResources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/mappers/*.xml");
            sqlSessionFactory.setMapperLocations(classPathResources);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() {
        log.debug("Creating MapperScannerConfigurer");
        MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("nl.somesite.teamshot.data");
        return mapperScannerConfigurer;
    }

}
```

AppConfig class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"nl.somesite.teamshot.config"})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

AppInitializer class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.initializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "nl.somesite.teamshot.config";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";

    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AppInitializer.class.getName());

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfig class:

```
package nl.somesite.teamshot.config;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WebMvcConfig.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =  new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Last part of logs:

```
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry line:220] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:449] Creating instance of bean 'dataSource'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractBeanFactory line:249] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dbConfig'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DbConfig line:25] Creating dataSource bean, url =  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teamshot?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DbConfig line:34] dataSource bean url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teamshot?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:523] Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:477] Finished creating instance of bean 'dataSource'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry line:220] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'sqlSessionFactory'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:449] Creating instance of bean 'sqlSessionFactory'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractBeanFactory line:249] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myBatisConfig'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [MyBatisConfig line:27] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver line:553] Looking for matching resources in directory tree [D:\Eclipse workspaces\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\teamshot\WEB-INF\classes\mappers]  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver line:615] Searching directory [D:\Eclipse workspaces\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\teamshot\WEB-INF\classes\mappers] for files matching pattern [D:/Eclipse workspaces/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/teamshot/WEB-INF/classes/mappers/*.xml]  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver line:354] Resolved location pattern [classpath*:/mappers/*.xml] to resources [file [D:\Eclipse workspaces\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\teamshot\WEB-INF\classes\mappers\newsitems.xml], file [D:\Eclipse workspaces\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\teamshot\WEB-INF\classes\mappers\teams.xml]]  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:523] Eagerly caching bean 'sqlSessionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory line:1595] Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry line:474] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3278a91: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,appConfig,dbConfig,myBatisConfig,propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerConfig,webMvcConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,dataSource,sqlSessionFactory,mapperScannerConfigurer,propertyConfigurer,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,internalResourceViewResolver,newsItemMapper,teamMapper]; root of factory hierarchy  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DisposableBeanAdapter line:322] Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DisposableBeanAdapter line:244] Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'webMvcConfig'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:20 [DisposableBeanAdapter line:244] Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'dbConfig'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:21 [DisposableBeanAdapter line:244] Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'appConfig'  
    [DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 01:25:21 [DisposableBeanAdapter line:244] Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerConfig'  
    [ERROR:] 2014-07-09 01:25:21 [ContextLoader line:331] Context initialization failed Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [nl/somesite/teamshot/config/MyBatisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required 
    jul 09, 2014 1:25:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [nl/somesite/teamshot/config/MyBatisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 22 more
```

If I disable Spring debug logging I see this:

```
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:19 [MyBatisConfig line:50] Creating MapperScannerConfigurer  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [DbConfig line:24] Creating dataSource bean, url =  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teamshot?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [DbConfig line:33] dataSource bean url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teamshot?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[DEBUG:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [MyBatisConfig line:30] Creating SqlSessionFactoryBean, dataSource = null  
[ERROR:] 2014-07-09 11:02:20 [ContextLoader line:331] Context initialization failed Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [nl/somesite/teamshot/config/MyBatisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

Comment: What component loads `MyBatisConfig`?

Comment: Edited the original posts, added all missing classes of the configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading a lot of Spring related stuff I discovered that the MapperScannerConfigurer is a implementation of BeanFactoryPostProcessor. Having a BeanFactoryPostProcessor in a @Configuration class breaks the default post-processing of that @Configuration class.

> There is a fundamental lifecycle conflict in handling
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor @Bean methods within @Configuration classes
>   that use @Autowired, @PostConstruct, @Value, etc. Because BFPPs must
>   be instantiated early in the lifecycle, they cause early instantiation
>   of their declaring @Configuration class - too early to recieve the
>   usual post-processing by AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and
>   friends.
>   See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8269

Separating the MapperScannerConfigurer bean method from MyBatisConfig into it's own class solves the problem.

Comment: would you share that configuration for the community/audience? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1:

Based on further input change the following:

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {}
```

TO

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {}
```

You should really setup session factory and db all in one class. Make life easier for yourself.

Great example is here:

http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate3-spring

Comment: Aeseir, I tried both @Import(DbConfig.class) and 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"nl.somesite.teamshot.config"}) but with no luck.

Comment: Does your IDE pick up the bean? Also can you show me your configuration (code) for the dataSource bean.

Comment: The code for the dataSource bean is in the code above in the DbConfig class.

Comment: Fixed the problem, in contrary to setup sqlSessionFactory and db all in one class I created a separate class for sqlSessionFactory. For some reason I don't know yet, the beans in the MyBatisConfig class were created first without waiting for the DbConfig beans to be available. Probably the MapperScannerConfigurer bean is the culprit here.
@Aeseir: thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a MapperScannerConfigurer bean, wouldn't this be simplified by using the annotation?

```
@MapperScan("com.acme.base.package")
```

Comment: com.acme.base.package is what?

Answer (score -2):

use annotation @AutoConfigureAfter in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure`

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})  
public class MybatisConfig {
...
}
```